# nested form is not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many

I have the following form declaration for a new kindergarten

```
<%= form_for @kindergarten, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f|%>

                <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
            </br>   
                <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
                    <%= p.label 'upload photo'%>
                    <%= p.file_field :image %>
                <% end %>
            </br>
                <%= render 'about_company', f: f%>
            </br>
                <%= render 'contact', f: f %>
                <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
            <%end%>
```

The logic behind this is that 1 kindergarten can have multiple photos.

Here are the model declarations:

Kindergarten

```
has_many :photos, limit: 7, dependent: :destroy   
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

Photo

```
  attr_accessible :image, :logo, :kindergarten_id
  belongs_to :kindergarten
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :kindergarten_id, presence: true
  validates :photo, presence: true
```

I am struggling with this for a few hours now, and I can't understand why the "upload file" button and label are not showing up. When i say now showing up, i mean they are completely ignored and not present in the rendered html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before rendering the form for a new @ kindergarden, you'll need to build a photo association for this to work:

```
def new
  @kindergarden = Kindergarden.new
  @kindergarden.photos.build # provides a photo object to use in the form
  # rest of your action
end
```

Also, if you wanted multiple photo fields in the form, you could do something like:

```
 5.times { @kindergarden.photos.build }
```

Comment: now i get this error: `undefined method 'photos' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I can't tell where you're getting this error. You'll need to provide more info.

Comment: it's just that and this: `app/controllers/kindergartens_controller.rb:5:in 'new'` . I've also updated the new action inside the controller and now it looks liike this:   `def new
    @kindergarten = Kindergarten.new
    @kindergarden.photos.build
  end`

Comment: I've also added a new question on this topic with the input you provided and the error:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547543/nested-form-display-error