# nested form display error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-many

I have the following form declaration for a new kindergarten

```
<%= form_for @kindergarten, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f|%>

            <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        </br>   
            <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
                <%= p.label 'upload photo'%>
                <%= p.file_field :image %>
            <% end %>
        </br>
            <%= render 'about_company', f: f%>
        </br>
            <%= render 'contact', f: f %>
            <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <%end%>
```

The logic behind this is that 1 kindergarten can have multiple photos.

Here are the model declarations:

Kindergarten

```
has_many :photos, limit: 7, dependent: :destroy   
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

Photo

```
  attr_accessible :image, :logo, :kindergarten_id
  belongs_to :kindergarten
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :kindergarten_id, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
```

And here's how the kindergartens controller looks like:

```
  def new
    @kindergarten = Kindergarten.new
    @kindergarden.photos.build
  end
```

Now, when @kindergarten new is generated i get the following error:

```
undefined method 'photos' for nil:NilClass

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/kindergartens_controller.rb:5:in `new'
```

Comment: Spelling error: kindergarten is not the same as kindergarden

Comment: now i feel like an idiot. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written `@kindergarden.photos.build` instead of `@kindergarten.photos.build`. I hope the typo is not in the actual code.
Also  try `@kindergarten=Kindergarten.create` . If you are calling new just creates an unsaved  record, which should be followed by a call to the save method. That could be the reason for the NilClass error.